# "Cannot find central directory" error appears when extracting 7z file using SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

There is no problem with .zip file but only 7z.

```
 FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(archiveFilenameIn);
            zf = new ZipFile(fs); // This is where we encountered an error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ZipFile` class only handles `.zip` files, not `.7z` files.

In fact, [`SharpZipLib` does not support `.7z` files at all](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FAQ).

A "central directory" is a list of all the files present in a zip-file and where they're located, used to speedily extract one file or get a file listing without reading the whole file.

Comment: Hi Lasse, thank you for answering my question. Would you know if there are good tools (free) out there that I could use? Mainly, what I need to achieve is to unzip this 7z file. My last resort is to use the 7z.exe but I don't want that. 

Really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know which libraries or whatnot would work for this.